# how to control font size of textarea after phpspellcheck action

Tags: php, jquery

I have implemented "Phpspellcheck" API to find auto suggestion for wrong spelled words.

```
<?php
#PHP Source Code
require "phpspellcheck/include.php";  //edit this path if necessary

$mySpell = new SpellAsYouType();
$mySpell->InstallationPath = "phpspellcheck/";
$mySpell->Fields = "ALL";
echo $mySpell->Activate();
?>
```

Everything is working fine but i got one serious issue.

My font-size inside textbox in 10. If i wrote incorrect word inside there, there appears red/green line under the words but with bigger font(i guess it is 13). I want the detected words to appear in size 10 too. I tried a lot but succeed. Anybody got an idea?

Thanks,
Biplab

Comment: We need the resulting html and css. Do you have a link?

Comment: yeah, i downloaded the API from here:
http://www.phpspellcheck.com/Download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty: edit the `context-menu.css` and add `font-size: 10px;` to the `livespell_redwiggle` and `livespell_greenwiggle` classes. The it should look like:

```
.livespell_redwiggle {
    ...
    font-size: 10px;
}

.livespell_greenwiggle {
    ...
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Better is to create a [custom theme](http://www.phpspellcheck.com/Custom_Styles_And_Themes#1_-_Create_a_Custom_Theme_Directory) with the changes above.

Comment: hey scessor, but after i right clicked and correct the spelling the font again goes big.....and after i start typing another word it readjust again. plz help me

Comment: May it helps when you change the `font-size` to `10px` for the `livespell_textarea` class in the same file.

Comment: no , i did that already.....it seems like it calls some javascript function where we should modify...i put font size everywhere in css..